# Como instalar react correctamente?

Tags: reactjs

trato de instalar react usando los comandos

```
init -y
npm i create-react-app
```

pero en el momento de la descarga solo aparece una carpera node_modules y package-lock que puedo hacer?

Comment: y como se llama tu proyecto???

Answer (score 0):

Nose si te refieres cuando ya usas el create-react-app o no, pero en el caso que solo lo instales y ya, lo que tienes que hacer es escribir en la consola:

`npx create-react-app **proyecto**`
De esta forma ya tienes tu proyecto react creado

En caso de que te salga error o no tengas npx, instalalo con npm:

`npm install npx`
**De que tengas que instalar npx no lo recuerdo, pero por si acaso lo digo**

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada necesitas instalado [node.js](https://nodejs.org/es/download/) que traera `npm` y `npx`.

Luego debes ejecutar lo siguientes comandos:

```
npx create-react-app my-app //my-app es el nombre de tu proyecto
cd my-app
npm start
```

Documentacion: [link](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)